# error when launch a magnum cluster

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

I use openstack newton and install magnum and other dependencies. I want deploy a cluster by k8s_fedora_atomic. I download fedora_atomic_newton. and my controller os is ubuntu16.04
I create a template cluster and when deploy own cluster from template, cluster status go to Created_Field state. below the my magnum-conductor log :

```
2018-08-14 14:26:28.999 26824 INFO magnum.conductor.handlers.cluster_conductor [req-bbf07a4c-a600-4797-8a40-7f3d6af64d6c 0f48db6ef8ee4d0c86ffe747579fe78c 7f5b52b3f61a4f71a00fc3f6c6d9232c default - -] Cluster has been deleted, stack_id: 53319edd-0a2e-4c3d-bca5-e30ef0544386
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall [req-7c3a7669-aa16-4b9a-b8f2-bd5570909c40 0f48db6ef8ee4d0c86ffe747579fe78c 7f5b52b3f61a4f71a00fc3f6c6d9232c default - -] Fixed interval looping call 'magnum.conductor.handlers.cluster_conductor.HeatPoller.poll_and_check' failed: ValueError: Field `master_addresses[0]' cannot be None
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_service/loopingcall.py", line 136, in _run_loop
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     result = func(*self.args, **self.kw)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magnum/conductor/handlers/cluster_conductor.py", line 330, in poll_and_check
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     self._sync_cluster_and_template_status(stack)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magnum/conductor/handlers/cluster_conductor.py", line 399, in _sync_cluster_and_template_status
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     self.cluster)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magnum/drivers/common/template_def.py", line 325, in update_outputs
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     output.set_output(stack, cluster_template, cluster)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magnum/drivers/common/k8s_fedora_template_def.py", line 39, in set_output
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     self).set_output(stack, cluster_template, cluster)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/magnum/drivers/common/template_def.py", line 122, in set_output
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     setattr(cluster, self.cluster_attr, output_value)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_versionedobjects/base.py", line 72, in setter
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     field_value = field.coerce(self, name, value)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_versionedobjects/fields.py", line 195, in coerce
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     return self._type.coerce(obj, attr, value)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_versionedobjects/fields.py", line 637, in coerce
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall     coerced_list.extend(value)
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service.loopingcall   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_versionedobjects/fields.py", line 1190, in extend
2018-08-14 15:17:23.846 26824 ERROR oslo.service ...
```